# Can a C++ function return without explicit giving type instantiation / with empty initializer list

Tags: c++, c++11

Assuming a function with complicated return type, can we simplify the return statement?(no need to specify detailed return type)

```
std::vector<std::map<int/*id*/, std::string/*data*/>> GetSomeData(int type) {
  if (type == DataType::Invalid) {
    return std::vector<std::map<int, std::string>>(); // this works
    return {}; // can we make this happen?
  }
}
```

I know there is another way doing that:

```
std::vector<std::map<int/*id*/, std::string/*data*/>> GetSomeData(int type) {
  std::vector<std::map<int, std::string>> ret;
  if (type == DataType::TypeA) {
    ....
    // filling ret here
  } else if (....) {
    ....
  }
  return ret;
}
```

But I'm still curious about this question.

Comment: `return {};` [works](https://godbolt.org/z/vY73j4snf). What error do you get?

Comment: Unrelated: Why is it `int type` instead of `DataType type`?

Comment: As long as the compiler knows (or can otherwise deduce) the function return type, `return {}` is fine (Assuming C++11 and later).   If you force the compiler to deduce the return type from the `return {}` statement, then the return type will be indeterminate (`{}` can match many types).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can. `{}` can be used to initialize an empty `std::vector<?>`. This code can be compiled in gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0 with command `g++ -o cpp-lab -std=c++11 main.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>

std::vector<std::map<int, std::string>> GetSomeData(int type) {

  return {};
}

// ... main function declaration ...
```

Comment: no gcc, it's g++ (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0